# Connected Character segmentation in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ocr, image-segmentation

What is a good method to segment characters that are united as in the following figure, knowing that:

- characters have this font, but the font size varies based on the image size
- only isolated groups of characters from the image are connected

[image]

Also, how can i detect if in a given bounding box, there are 2 or more letters which are connected?

I tried with checking for width > height for detecting connected characters but it doesn't work for the blue groups in the image.

I also tried a segmentation method based on:
[Article section 3.4](http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/40725/InTech-Preprocessing_for_images_captured_by_cameras.pdf)
for separating characters but got poor results.

Comment: yes, it doesn't work since it splits letters too much, especially in the case of "u", "n".

Comment: Is this solved?

Answer (score 6):

**IDEA**: if you have a good ocr already, you can try to apply ocr all these connected components (or contours). If ocr cant detect a letter; than there is not 1 letter, there are 2 or more.

**IDEA**: check [convexity defects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143077/computer-vision-opencv-filtering-convex-hulls-and-convexity-defects) of these connected components, the closest defect points are where the bridges are.

**IDEA**: use a kernel having small width & big height for erosion+dilation ([morphological opening](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html))

**IDEA**: take y-derivative of the image. The smallest contours (or lines) left will be your bridges. Mark them and erase those pixels from the original image.

**IDEA**: search problem approach: Take 2 letters from alphabet (and this font), connect them horizontally with some tool and use [matchShapes](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes) method (moment match) of opencv to find if that shape matches with your connected component. Or try to implement [autocorrelation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160868/A-C-Project-in-Optical-Character-Recognition-OCR-U).

good luck.